# How to fix this problem with assertEquals in Junit?

Tags: java, junit

Please help me with the following problem, My Junit test fails because my output is

```
"09:39:43.704 [main] INFO by.iba.gomel.ShapeController - 145"
```

But i need just "145" `ShapeController.LOGGER.info("{}", ShapeController.sum);`

```
@Test
public void testSumma() {

    final Shape[] newShapes = new Shape[5];
    ShapeController.initializeArray(newShapes);
    ShapeController.summa(newShapes);
    Assert.assertEquals("these objects should be  equal", "145", this.log.getLog());
}
```

Comment: Use another log format for the tests?

Comment: Can you access the field `ShapeController.sum` directly? If not, is there a getter available you can use to access the value of `ShapeController.sum`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not changing the log format and the class name you can use `this.log.getLog().split("ShapeController - ")[1]`.

But be wary of such hard-coded things. Anyways if you change something this test case will break and notify you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java Library such as  [Hamcrest](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/)  to make an assertion in a sentence if it ends with the number or word, such as [1](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/CoreMatchers.html#endsWith(java.lang.String)) :

```
assertThat("myStringOfNote", endsWith("Note"))
```

This can be translated into your use case as :

```
assertThat(this.log.getLog(), endsWith("145"))
```